# remove duplicates from dynamic multilevel nested object using JS

Tags: javascript, nested-object

I have nested json object in which, I need to remove the objects which have duplicate keys.
For Example: In the given array, I need to remove duplicate items from edit, new & delete on the bases of "value" key. I have tried multiple methods but I'm not able to do it dynamically.

```
let json = {
  edit:{
     params:[],
     items:[
        {
           id:"1",
           source:"text",
           value:"new1"
        },
     ]
  },
  delete:{
     params:[],
     items:[
        {
           id:"2",
           source:"text",
           value:"new2"
        },
     ]
  },
  new:{
     params:[],
     items:[
        {
           id:"3",
           source:"text",
           value:"new1"
        },
        {
           id:"4",
           source:"text",
           value:"new"
        },
        {
           id:"5",
           source:"text",
           value:"new2"
        },
        {
           id:"6",
           source:"text",
           value:"new"
        },
     ]
  },
  text:{
     name:"test",
     value:"test",
     id:"10"
  }
}
```

Expected output should be:

```
let result = {
  edit:{
     params:[],
     items:[
        {
           id:"1",
           source:"text",
           value:"new1"
        }
     ]
  },
  delete:{
     params:[],
     items:[
        {
           id:"2",
           source:"text",
           value:"new2"
        }
     ]
  },
  new:{
     params:[],
     items:[
        {
           id:"4",
           source:"text",
           value:"new"
        }
     ]
  },
  text:{
     name:"test",
     value:"test",
     id:"10"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to have an array hold all the parsed values while looping though the items, and filter the items based on their inclusion in that array:

```js
// Create empty array of values to use to check for duplicates
const values = [];

// Create empty result object
const result = {};

// Loop through the edit, delete, new and text keys from the json
Object.keys(json).forEach(key => {
  const obj = json[key];

  // Loop through items and filter out non-duplicates
  const items = obj.items.filter(item => !values.includes(item.value));

  // Store the items values in the duplicate check array
  items.forEach(item => values.push(item.value));

  // Add the key to the results
  result[key] = { 
    ...obj, // Spread all values from the original obj
    items, // Overwrite the items
  };
});
```